# Outlook 2011 won't close in Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

Outlook 2011 has frozen in the middle of moving an email and won't close. How can I close it?

Comment: beside force quit, are you trying to fix outlook ?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to Force Quit a application.

The following is probably easiest.

Bring Up the “Force Quit Applications” Window

Hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the “Force Quit Applications” window, then click to select the app name, followed by clicking the “Force Quit” button to end the app immediately.

[image: force quit]

Or, you could use the Activity Monitor to Force Quit application.

<sub>PS, it is also a quick way to see what apps are running</sub> :)